# How do I produce an FFI function with a `main`-like interface?

Tags: rust, ffi

I am trying to use rust to interface with an ancient platform that expects the functions to be declared and externed in a specific C-Style format.

```
char *func(int argc, char *argv[])
```

I am trying to reproduce this signature in Rust. I need to be able to properly parse arguments (ideally as Rust Strings) and then return an arbitrary value as a string without disrupting the signature.

So far, I have the following:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn my_function(argc: isize, argv: *const c_char) -> (CString) {

    let output: CString = CString::new("Test Output").expect("CString::new failed");

    return output;
}
```

Which properly returns my test string through the interface, but I can't figure out how to parse argv into a usable format, or if my implementation of argv is even properly compliant with the specified format. I am not familiar with pointers, and I am not even sure where to start with figuring this out.

Comment: I understand this format is used in C/C++ style int main() to pass command line arguments (sometimes) but rust's main automatically handles this. This is only partially related to my question, I feel.

Comment: Is the returned string ever meant to be freed later? If so, you'd have to pass it back to Rust at some point.

Comment: Your `argv` is incorrect, it should be `argv: *const *const c_char`

Comment: The interface I am using (BYOND DLL calls) does not ever give the string back. Despite Rust telling me that CString is not FFI safe, returning a CString behaves how I want it to, so I am going o keep that. The argument parsing in the accepted answer is working wonderfully though.

Comment: Right, it's the distinction between "it works now" and "it will keep working". There's not guaranteed that using `CString` won't randomly break some time when you update Rust, that's why you want to stick with `*mut c_char` for the return. Returning `CString` is basically force-casting a `CString` into a `*mut c_char` instead of doing it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your existing code, you have a few primary issues:

1. `argv: *const c_char` is wrong because the original C code is an array of pointers, not a pointer to a char. The correct type is

   ```
   argv: *const *const c_char
   ```
2. You cannot return `CString` because that is not a type that C will know what to do with. You need to return `*mut c_char` just like the C function did. To do this, you use [`output.into_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.into_raw) to unwrap the string and get the underlying `*mut c_char` pointer. This also means that you are giving this C code a random pointer, and it can read it as a C string, but it can't free that memory, so you're either leaking that memory, or you need a second function to pass the string back to Rust to be freed later using [`from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.from_raw). In this case I'm using `*mut c_char` because that's what `into_raw` returns.
3. You should consistently use the `c_` types for everything in the C interface, including `argc`, e.g.

   ```
   my_function(argc: c_int, argv: *const *const c_char) -> *mut c_char
   ```

To process the args, you want to loop through the `argc` values to wrap each pointer into a [`CStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html), which you can then work with without needing to worry about unsafe code.

All taken together:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn my_function(argc: c_int, argv: *const *const c_char) -> *mut c_char {
    
    let argv: Vec<_> = (0..argc)
        .map(|i| unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(*argv.add(i as usize)) })
        .collect();

    // Whatever processing you need to do.

    let output = CString::new("Test Output").expect("CString::new failed");

    return output.into_raw();
}
```

and potentially

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn my_function_free(s: *mut c_char) {
    unsafe {
        CString::from_raw(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried so many different things that I hadn't even realized I cut my type down. At one point I had had *const *const c_char but tried shortening it at some point....

I was simply not familiar enough with rust to know of map and collect, I find the way low level arrays are used very weird...